# get all form elements that end with "Max" as the id name

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I basically have several input fields that share the same last 3 characters, "Max". They are all different from the "div" tags they are part of. The block of code I have right now looks terrible:

```
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["MCQMax"]) > 0)
                {
                    TempData["Max"] = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["MCQMax"]);
                }
                else if (Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["SAMax"]) > 0)
                {
                    TempData["Max"] = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["SAMax"]);
                }
                else if (Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["PLMCQMax"]) > 0)
                {
                    TempData["Max"] = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["PLMCQMax"]);
                }
                else if (Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["PLIFMax"]) > 0)
                {
                    TempData["Max"] = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["PLIFMax"]);
                }
                else if (Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["PLDMax"]) > 0)
                {
                    TempData["Max"] = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["PLDMax"]);
                }
```

How do i pass in any form elements that end with Max instead of having this redundant block of code?Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var firstMaxFormKey = Request.Form.AllKeys
     .Where(arg => arg.EndsWith("Max"))
     .FirstOrDefault();
TempData["Max"] = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form[firstMaxFormKey]);
```

**[Edit]**

I'm sorry didn't pay enough attention. I think this is what you need:

```
var max = Request.Form.AllKeys
        .Where(arg => arg.EndsWith("Max"))
        .Select(arg => Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form[arg]))
        .Where(arg => arg > 0)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Trying this, Thanks for replying!

Comment: @ValianthX -  I updated my answer with a little better code sample. Hope this is what you actually need.

Answer (score 1):

You could put all of the IDs into an array and then just loop through them:

(untested semi-pseudocode)

```
IDs={"MCAMax",...}

for(int i=0; i<IDs.length; i++){
   int theMax=Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form[IDs[i]]);
   if ( theMax > 0){
      TempData["Max"] = theMax;
      break;
   }
}
```